# How to execute efficient communication for multiple (micro)services?

Tags: php, rest, restful-architecture, microservices

**Case:** Software build with many microservices and internal services.

**The doubt** is how to manage performance issues (network latency, size of resource) getting multiple resources from many microservices at once.

I Just can not imagine making 20 HTTP requests to access all necessary resources.

Comment: If you need to somehow query a result from 20 services, then you somehow have to make requests to 20 services... You could try to approach this in an asynchronous way to reduce the waiting time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce the number of requests made you might create a facade that encapsulates incoming API calls. This enables you to get rid of expensive network roundtrips.

Netflix blogged about a very similar challenge

http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/01/optimizing-netflix-api.html

http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/07/embracing-differences-inside-netflix.html